# Как провести сортировку при использовании friendly_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

В проекте используется гем friendly_id по полю name.
Как провести сортировку в запросе?
Если делать что то вроде:`Model.all.order(name: :asc)`, то сортировка идет в итоге по полю slug, а т.к. name на русском возникает проблема.

**Update**

model job.rb:

```
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
```

model example.rb:

```
  belongs_to :job
```

Пытаюсь сделать примерно следующее:

```
 ExampleJob.all.includes(:job).order("LOWER('jobs.name') DESC")
```

Еще пробовал:

```
    Job.where(id: ids_arr).order(name: :desc)
```

Логи:

```
Job.all.order(name: :desc)
 Job Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs"  ORDER BY "jobs"."name" DESC
=> [#<Job:0x007fd316133558 id: 2, name: "Диагностика", created_at:..., slug: "diagnostika">,
 #<Job:0x007fd316133328 id: 3, name: "Установка", created_at: ..., slug: "ustanovka">,
 #<Job:0x007fd3161330a8 id: 1, name: "Замена", created_at: ..., slug: "zamena">]
```

Т.е по названию должно было бы быть: Диагностика, Замена, Установка, очевидно все таки тут отсортировано по slug

**P.S.**
 БД postgresql 9.3

```
Job.all.order(name: :desc).explain
  Job Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs"  ORDER BY "jobs"."name" DESC
=> EXPLAIN for: SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs"  ORDER BY "jobs"."name" DESC
                          QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=51.37..53.17 rows=720 width=84)
   Sort Key: name DESC
   ->  Seq Scan on jobs  (cost=0.00..17.20 rows=720 width=84)
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Не должна идти сортировка по `slug`, если только вы явно не указали это, например в модели. Сможете дополнить вопрос кодом из модели, которым вы подключаете к ней FriendlyId?

Comment: @ВиталийЕмельянцев обновил

Comment: БД у вас какая? Потому что SQL-запрос определённо правильный, а сортировать данные после выгрузки из БД это крайне опрометчивый шаг для friendly_id, вряд ли он таким занимается.

Comment: @D-side конкретно в данной задаче friendly_id мне вообще не нужен, но он используется в других частях проекта, БД postgresql 9.3

Comment: Покажите вывод `Job.all.order(name: :desc).pluck(:name)`

Comment: @D-side `Job.all.order(name: :desc).pluck(:name)
   (1327.0ms)  SELECT "jobs"."name" FROM "jobs"  ORDER BY "jobs"."name" DESC
=> ["Диагностика", "Установка", "Замена"]`

Comment: Это странно. `Job.all.order(name: :desc).explain` что говорит?

Comment: @D-side добавил вывод в вопрос

Comment: `psql -l` что пишет для вашей БД в encoding, collation и ctype?